# How to create an Admin page for a website developed in React + Node?

Tags: reactjs, admin, material-ui

I want to create an Admin page in order to manage users, groups, passwords and to publish content in a website. That website is made using React.

What is the right way to make it? Using a library for React that provides such Admin?

My workmate told me he uses Material UI, but I don't see how that library could be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Material UI is used only for styling stuff, not for actual logic. If you have a REST backend, take a look at [admin on rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) project.

What is your backed written in?

Comment: It's written in plain NodeJS, Mongo and Express. Do you use Admin on Rest often, @Toni?